# Read specific XML nested node using DOM with VBA

Tags: xml, vba, dom, msxml

I want to read out values of one or two nested nodes of an XML file by using VBA. (I tried to use DOM (`MSXML.DOMDocument`).)

For example, I want to determine, from the following XML, that the `/szamla/fejlec/elado/nev/` node's value is "Budapesti Elektromos Művek Nyrt."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-2" ?>
<szamla szamkor="000000200267" szafaz="800101068670" feldolgazon="35245830" 
   ugyfelaz="2200502333">
<fejlec>
<elado>
<nev>Budapesti Elektromos Művek Nyrt.</nev> 
<adoszam>10768033-2-44</adoszam> 
<cim>
 <orszag>Magyarország</orszag> 
 <telepules>Budapest</telepules> 
 <irszam>1132</irszam> 
 <kozternev>Váci út 72-74.</kozternev> 
</cim>
</elado>
...

<szamla szamkor="000000200267" szafaz="800101068670" feldolgazon="35245830" 
   ugyfelaz="2200502333">
```

This seems to be very basic, but I haven't been able to figure how to do it for hours.

Comment: how are you reading the code/text/xml in? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, see if it gives you any ideas

```
Sub thing()

    Dim xmldoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Set xmldoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    xmldoc.loadXML "<one><two><three><four></four></three></two></one>"
    MsgBox xmldoc.selectSingleNode("/one/two/three/four").nodeName

End Sub
```

The reference is to `Microsoft XML, v4.0`. For me, this is located at C:\WINNT\system32\msxml4.dll.

Comment: `.nodeName` will return "four" which you already know, for the text inside the node use `.Text`